# Scraping with HtmlUnit in Java (How to find the elements)

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, htmlunit

I need to get about 70 documents from `www.genios.de` . Every document has its own link and you have to login in to the WebSite to get access to the documents.

While I could to this manually I want to do this in Java just to learn to code better.

I found HtmlUnit, which seems to provide all the methods I need. My problem is, that I'm not able to get the TextFields for username/password and the button to login.

I tried different ways but none of them works. One attempt was the following code :

```
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.genios.de");
    final List<HtmlForm> forms =  (List<HtmlForm>) page1.getForms();
    final HtmlForm form = forms.get(0);
    HtmlInput usernameInput = form.getInputByName("loginBlock_username");
```

Resulting in:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[input] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[loginBlock_username]
    at    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.getInputByName(HtmlForm.java:469)
    at GeniosLogin.main(GeniosLogin.java:26)
```

Comment: did u try to use CSS selectors, when you select the field you want, in Chrome browser for example you can select inspect and then css selector.

Comment: (never worked with HtmlForm before) but does it have a `getInputById` that you could use? or try `getInputByName("loginBlock.username")`?

Comment: @Anja

For some reason there is no 'getInputById' . 

loginBlock.username works! But how did you find this? I'm also looking for the loginButton since neither loginBlock_c2 nor loginBlock.c2 seems to work with 'getButtonByName'.

Comment: if you press F12 you can navigate to the element, there you see the name. pw input is same format: `loginBlock.password`. As for the Login "button", it's not an actual input button but a `<span>`, prolly triggered by js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the field is 'loginBlock_username'.  The actual name of the field you are trying to get is 'loginBlock.username'

Comment: It works! But where did you read the name? 

I guss it was here? 
    jQi('loginBlock_username').jasty("TextBox", "init",     [{"id":"loginBlock.username", 

Even if it says id, it is the only line I found with "loginBlock.username". 

Not I have problems with getting the login button to work. Though it should be like this: 

         HtmlButton login = form.getButtonByName("loginBlock.c2");
  HtmlPage page2 = login.click();


But it isn't working. =/

Comment: This is the markup on the page  <input id="loginBlock_username" class="formText jasty-textbox" type="text" **name="loginBlock.username"** tabindex="1001" placeholder="Benutzername oder E-Mail">

Comment: I clicked "show code" in chrome, and I searched for loginBlock.username. The only match is : jQi('loginBlock_username').jasty("TextBox", "init", [{"id":"loginBlock.username",......)
Ho did you see the markup?

Comment: I just inspected the user input control in chrome dev tools.

Comment: How? 

I'm looking at the html source. Shouldn't everything that I need be there?

Comment: Right click over the user input control for entering your email and select inspect.  This will draw focus to the markup for that control.  It should be the fourth attribute to be displayed to you.

Comment: Thanks! 

It worked. But for some reason it says my username/password are wrong.  But they aren't. Could it be something about the cookies? I realized, that the webclient of htmlunit doesn't allow cookies even if it says so. You can't login into Genios if you don't allow cookies.

Comment: Depending upon the authentication mechanism being used, cookies associated with authentication are usually returned as part of the login response to persist the login state of the session.

Comment: @Andi92 can you mark this as now answered.  Cheers.